# NodeJS find query inside for loop results after the loops end

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

```
var user_id = '98-XXXXXXXX'

Contact.find({user_id: user_id})
.exec(function (err, results) {
  if (err) { 
    return next(err); 
  }
    var finalArray = [];
    for(var i = 0; i< results[0].Total; i++) {

      if(results[0].Contacts[i].name != "SPAM") {

       for(var j = 0; j < results[0].Contacts[i].phoneNumbers.length; j++){

           var number = results[0].Contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j].number
           number = number.replace(/ /g,'');
            var user_id = number.substr(number.length - 10); 

                Login.find({user_id:user_id})
                .exec(function(err,results) {
                if(err) {
                return next(err); }

                    var intCount = results.length;
                        if (intCount > 0)
                        {
                            console.log('called')
                            finalArray.push(results[0])
                            console.log(finalArray)
                        } 
               });

            }
         }

        //console.log(i,results[0].Total - 1);
        //if(i == results[0].Total - 1)



    } 
                    console.log('Ended Here',finalArray)
                    var responseTosend = {"message":finalArray,"user_id":user_id}
                    return  res.send(responseTosend);

});
```

EndedHere[] this is coming up first empty, after that i got the result of login.find query which is correct. Any ideas how to get the finalArray after all the calculation. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the functions are returning promises within the loops, the code execution has to wait till all those promises are resolved. Consider using `Promise.all` or `Promise.map` to wait. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: I am new to nodeJS can you please give a snippet of code for a reference how it really works

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, a structure like this, will not return the results, but the intermediate functions or objects before they are finished, since nodejs does not know it should await the results first.

```
const x = [1,2,3]
let results = []

for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
  results.push(someAsyncJobLikeADatabaseCall(x[i]))
}

// this will not return the results, but the intermediate async objects/functions
console.log(results)
```

Here is a better version using promises and the .map function. Notice, how we replaced the for loop with .map() (which you could see as a shorthand for .forEach + push() or for() + push(). Mongoose returns Promises if configured right, so you don't even have to manually define them and we can directly return them in .map.

```
const x = [1,2,3]
let results = []

async function getAsyncResults(array){
  // map returns an array, this time, an array of promises
  const promises = x.map(number => someAsyncJobLikeADatabaseCall(number))
  // Promise.all resolves, if all promises in the array have been resolved
  return Promise.all(promises)
}

try {
  let results = await getAsyncResults(x)
  // this will return the results you expect.
  console.log(results)
} catch (err) {
  console.log('Some error', err)
}
```